# Deleting ALL selected rows from datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I am using datagridview to view a SQL Table on Windows Form and I was hoping to use this to be able to add/delete rows from the SQL table.

I am using the following code to delete the selected rows from the datagridview:

```
        try
        {
            int count = dataGridView.SelectedRows.Count;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView.SelectedRows)
            {
                TA.DeleteQuery(item.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Logs.LogEvent(3, ex.Message + "\n" + ex.ToString()); }
        finally { UpdateTable(); }
```

This code deletes all rows except the first row that is selected. When I step through the code the dataGridView selected rows count keeps displaying one less than the value selected which is what I expected but the foreach loop only iterates through 3 times. When I used a for loop to iterate through 4 times it gave me an out of range error!

Have you guys any idea why this might be and if there is a better way to approach this?

Let me know if you need more details.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: So that `count` variable gets loaded with a 3, right?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your comment: _”the dataGridView selected rows count keeps displaying one less than the value selected which is what I expected…”_ ? … Why would you expect this? If there are three (3) rows selected, then `dataGridView.SelectedRows.Count` will return three (3). Why would you expect otherwise? The “foreach” loop looks ok. I would look closer at your query.

Comment: @JorgeY. Yes the count is loaded with 3 if I select 4 rows

Comment: @JohnG Normally the software count starts from 0 so if I select 4 rows it only counts up to 3. Now that I think about it I may be wrong to expect that because if no rows are selected the count should give me a 0. When I try to delete for example from Row 1 to Row 8 it deletes all rows except the first row. So it begs the question why the first row selected is not counted.

Comment: In most collections (like the `SelectedRows` collection), the indexing into that collection starts with zero (0). Therefore, if there are four (4) rows in the collection, then the FIRST row (1) is at index 0, second row (2) at index 1, third row (3) at index 2 and the last row (4) at index 3. However, this has nothing to do with HOW MANY rows are in the collection. How you count them is irrelevant, 0,1,2,3 is four (4) elements and so is 1,2,3,4. This is why your comment is incorrect, the loops (implemented properly) will always loop four (4) times… not three (3) as you stated.

Comment: @JohnG Starting with your first comment, the first of the selected row is what I meant. Everything I meant in the questions and comments are rows that are selected. Those that are not selected are irrelevant. And so eliminating all other than what is selected we have 4 rows selected. As you mentioned it is logical to expect the count to be 3 which goes from 0 to 3. But there are only 0 to 2 and the count shows 3 and the ResultView shows row0 row1 and row2. row3 is not there, after the delete the first row that was SELECTED is not deleted.

Comment: @JohnG The query is as simple as Delete From [tablename] Where ID = ID there is literally nothing can go wrong here and it always returns the number of rows deleted which is always 1 in each iteration of the loop. Ill give you a better example. I have selected 4 rows, Item1, Item2, Item3, and Item4 (Yes the rows are highlighted on the datagridview) when I come to the foreach and step through the executed code the forloop starts at Item2 and deletes it, Item3 and deletes it and Item4 and deletes it and the foreach loop completes. This to me suggests that Item1 is missed out by SelectedRows

Comment: [How to delete multiple rows in DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38335117/3110834)

Comment: You will have to demonstrate what you describe. From the code you posted, I cannot reproduce the problem. If there are four selected rows, the “foreach” loop executes four times. There must be something else going on.

Comment: @JohnG that is what I am trying to get to the bottom of, there must be something that is not omitting the first row from the selection. It seems to be unique only for that datagridview. I used the same datagridview on a different form and like you said, the code works perfectly. I suppose I have to stick to that for the time being.

Comment: You may want to show more code, the small about of code you posted does not to appear to demonstrate what you describe. Better yet, post some code that we can copy and paste and get the same issue you describe. If you think it is the grid that is messed up (which it may well be) and you are adding it in the designer, then dump it and add a new one.

Comment: @JohnG I think the problem was with the particular version of the VS 2017 I was using. I've put the details in the answer. Thank you for your support! :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Just to clarify, I know how to delete rows from a dataGridView. The bizarre behaviour was caused by the version of Visual Studio that I was using that may have had a bug in it. After I upgraded it the above code worked fine. Also you deleted some of my tags which included Visual Studio in there. That was the issue so I'm gonna put that tag back on.

Comment: @ShibleeMarsuik Visual Studio tag should be used for questions about Visual Studio in itself. Anyway, I'm not going to revert it back if you believe the tag is useful. But I believe the solution cannot be related to version of Visual studio, because the running application doesn't have anything to do with Visual Studio. It can be related to .NET Framework version (I doubt it is even related to .NET framework version). I believe if you can not reproduce the problem, it's better to remove the question :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem may have been a bug on the version of the visual studio that I was using. When I upgraded the version to 15.5.7 (I can't remember what version it was before) the problem has disappeared. This may be the reason why others could not reproduce this problem.

It was something that I had at the back of my mind all the time but I wanted to exhaust all my other options.